# Get a URL of a GIT repository on my server

Tags: git

I've started using codebase to manage my GIT repositories. I also have GIT installed on my Debain box. There is an option on codebase to "Push to External Repository" which I'd like to do. This requires a URL, but all I have is the path on my server: `git@12.34.56.78:/srv/git/project.git`

Should I be setting a path up in my virtual hosts? Or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have all you need xylar, except a **ssh key** probably.

All you have to do now is set up a ssh key on the debian machine, and copy the key into your codebase.

With the ssh key codebase can access your server without a password.
In codebase the remote repository is `git@debianIP:/path/to/repo/project.git`